# O insert do Node.JS e Express com problema

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js, express.js

Eu sou novo como programador Node.JS Express com MySQL, eu criei a implementação para salvar, porém ele criar o registro com null na tabela, veja como realizei o teste no postman;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é minha entidade;

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Customer = sequelize.define('customer', {
      firstname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      lastname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      age: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      }
    });
    
    return Customer;
}
```

Esse é o método responsável em salvar;

```
const db = require('../config/db.config.js');
const Customer = db.customers;

// Post a Customer
exports.create = (req, res) => {    
    // Save to MySQL database
    Customer.create({  
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname,
      age: req.body.age
    }).then(customer => {       
        // Send created customer to client
        res.send(customer);
    });
};
```

**O que pode está havendo de errado?**

ATUALIZAÇÃO ================================

Arquivo de rotas;

```
module.exports = function(app) {
 
    const customers = require('../controller/customer.controller.js');
 
    // Create a new Customer
    app.post('/api/customers', customers.create);
 
    // Retrieve all Customer
    app.get('/api/customers', customers.findAll);
 
    // Retrieve a single Customer by Id
    app.get('/api/customers/:customerId', customers.findById);
 
    // Update a Customer with Id
    app.put('/api/customers/:customerId', customers.update);
 
    // Delete a Customer with Id
    app.delete('/api/customers/:customerId', customers.delete);
}
```

=======================================================

Gerou esse erro;

```
C:\SQL\api1>node server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/customer.controller'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SQL\api1\app\route\customer.route.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SQL\api1\server.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
```

=======================================

Outra mensagem de erro;

```
node server.js
C:\SQL\api1\server.js:15
app.use('/api/customers', routes);
                          ^

ReferenceError: routes is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SQL\api1\server.js:15:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:236:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:560:3)
```

Comment: Desculpe, onde você acha que deveria haver colchetes?

Comment: O que ele quer dizer é que você deveria tentar retirar "[" e "]", que denotam um array de objetos, e enviar somente o conteúdo entre "{" e "}", que é o objeto em si.

Comment: Por favor, em que parte do meu código devo retirar o "[" e "]"   ?

Comment: No Postman, não no seu código.

Comment: acontece a mesma coisa se eu for mudar de  body para raw, eu gostaria de saber do @StatelessDev o que eu poderia mudar no Postman para salvar os registros?

Comment: como seria alteração?

Comment: acabei de colocar, verifica a atualização da minha postagem por favor.

Comment: eu acredito que o comando console.log somente funcione no navegador, mesmo assim eu tentei e não apareceu nada, nem no navegador e nem no console do msdos

Comment: @Sorack infelizmente sua resposta não ajudou, e ainda estou tentando resolver meu problema, ele gerou alguns erros na própria IDE de desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro problema ocorre que o tipo de `body` que você está utilizando no `Postman` está incorreto. Use o `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

[image: Postman]

---

Verificando o código que você disponibilizou no seu repositório, sugiro as seguintes alterações:

No `server.js`:

```
const express    = require('express');
const app        = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db         = require('./app/config/db.config.js');
const customer   = require('./app/route/customer.route');

// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
  console.log('Drop and Resync with { force: true }');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// Registra a rota /api/customer para as rotas descritas em ./app/route/customer.route.js
app.use('/api/customers', customer);

// Create a Server
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

O arquivo de rotas ficará da seguinte forma (`app/route/customer.route.js`):

```
const customer = require('../controller/customer.controller');
const express  = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', customer.create);

module.exports = router;
```

Por sua vez o `controller` (`app/controller/customer.controller.js`):

```
const db = require('../config/db.config.js');
const Customer = db.customers;

async function create(req, res) {
  try {
    req.send(await _save(req.body));
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
}

async function _save(customer) {
  return Customer.create({  
    firstname: customer.firstname,
    lastname:  customer.lastname,
    age:       customer.age
  });
}

module.exports = {
  create
}
```

Comment: Eu coloquei o método no controller, a classe de rotas não consegue enxergar o método salva como acontece com os outros método que existem na classe controller, vou deixar disponível meu repositório `https://github.com/wladyband/node_com_mysql`

Gostaria de agradecer em tentar me ajudar.

Comment: Poderia por favor dar uma olhada na minha postagem, acabei de atualizar, quando mandei compilar ele gerou um erro. Talvez não precisaríamos perder muito tempo com esse meu projeto, eu não o desenvolvi, e encontrei ele na internet. Tudo que preciso é um projeto Node Expresse com MySQL que seja um CRUD que esteja funcionando, porém que use a implementação de Models. eu sei criar um projeto com CRUD com mysql, mas ele não usar models, e me disseram que utilizar o models é uma prática.

Comment: eu tentei analisar a alteração que você fez no arquivo `customer.route.js` mas não conseguir enxergar.

Comment: Você pode clicar no indicador abaixo da resposta "editada ?? mins atrás" para ver a alteração

Comment: eu atualizei a postagem, deu outra mensagem de erro.

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, consegui ter sucesso, muito obrigado pela paciência. muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @wladyband estamos aí pra isso